# Why does the CI() function in R return different results than qnorm for a 95% confidence interval?

Tags: r, statistics

When calculating the 95% CI for the sample mean in R, I get different results when using the CI function `CI(mydata)` and when I use `qnorm(.975, mean = mean(mydata), sd = sd(mydata))` for the upper bound and `qnorm(.025, mean = mean(mydata), sd = sd(mydata))` for the lower bound.

Why would there be a difference? The qnorm function provides results that make sense when looking at the plot of the probability distribution for my data.

Here is the code that I am using to generate 500 normal random variables, calculate the mean(xbar), standard deviation(s) and 95% CI:

```
mydata <- rnorm(500)
xbar <- mean(mydata)
xbar
```

[1] -0.0376074

```s
s
```

[1] 1.004922

`CI(mydata)`

```
 upper        mean       lower
```

0.05069041 -0.03760740 -0.12590521

Then using qnorm I get the following:

`qnorm(.975, mean=xbar, sd=s)`

[1] 1.932003

`qnorm(.025, mean=xbar, sd=s)`

[1] -2.007218

Comment: Where can we find function `CI`?

Comment: Hi @RuiBarradas- the ```CI``` function is in the package Rmisc

Answer (score 1):

From https://rdrr.io/cran/Rmisc/src/R/CI.R, the code underlying CI turns out to be
as follows.

```
CI <-
function(x,ci=.95) {
  a<-mean(x)
  s<-sd(x)
  n<-length(x)
  error<-qt(ci+(1-ci)/2,df=n-1)*s/sqrt(n)
  return(c(upper=a+error,mean=a,lower=a-error))
}
```

The use of `qt` indicates that the quantile of a t-distribution with `n-1` degrees of freedom is used to determine the lower and upper bound of the confidence interval. If you use `qnorm()`, then you get a different result. The differences will be especially noticeable when `n` is small.

I hope this answers your question.